# retrieve object id from relation in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

i have a model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :meetings, :dependent => :destroy do 
    def find_foreign
      Meeting.where("user_id <> ?", id)
    end
  end

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

end
```

and when i am trying to get user's foreign meetings like that

```
some_user.meetings.find_foreign
```

i get an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation):
```

because self in find_foreign is an Array. How to retrive the User.id from this method ?

Comment: what do you want to retrieve user's id or user's meeting's id?because if you have `some_user` that means you have user's id and if you can access `some_user.meetings` that means you have user's meeting's id.Can you please be clear about your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access `self` here:

```
def find_foreign
  Meeting.where("user_id <> ?", self.id)
end
```

But don't know why you've written this?

`some_user.meetings` will already filter meetings by current user id. I've even no idea if block is allowed here!

Answer (score 0):

`find_foreign` method is in `User Model` and you are trying to call it on `Array of the Object of the Meetings`

Just use

```
some_user.find_foreign
```